# How to generate share link in google drive using API?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps

I want to open (read an write) files like how google drive works. But I don't know how implement this. I thought it is possible with share link which I have done in one-drive. If anybody have an idea please share with  me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Google Drive v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files)

Use the property `alternateLink`

> `alternateLink`
>
> - A link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer.

Java Script sample Code:

```
/**
* Print a file's metadata.
*
* @param {String} fileId ID of the file to print metadata for.
*/
function printFile(fileId) {
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
'fileId': fileId
});
request.execute(function(resp) {
console.log('Title: ' + resp.title);
console.log('Description: ' + resp.description);
console.log('MIME type: ' + resp.mimeType);
console.log('Alternative link: '+resp.alternateLink)
});
}
```

## [Google Drive v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files)

Use the property `webViewLink`

> `webViewLink`
>
> - A link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser.

Java Script sample Code:

```
/**
* Print files.
*/
function listFiles() {
var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
'pageSize': 10,
'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink)"
});

request.execute(function(resp) {
appendPre('Files:');
var files = resp.files;
if (files && files.length > 0) {
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
var file = files[i];
appendPre(file.name + ' (' + file.id + ')' + file.weblink);
}
} else {
appendPre('No files found.');
}
});
}
```

## Note:

In v3, field `parameter` is used to get the desired property of the file.